# Multiple actions were found that match the request when using actions in Route config

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm currently building an API using Web API 2.2

I have the RESTful part of it working but now I need one non-RESTful controller:

```
 public class PremisesController : ApiController
    {
        private PremiseService _service;

        public PremisesController()
        {
            _service = new PremiseService();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Premise(string id)
        {
            id = id.Replace(" ", String.Empty).ToUpper();

            List<Premise> premises = _service.GetPremisesForPostcode(id);
            return Ok(premises);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Building(string id)
        {
            double premise = Convert.ToDouble(id);
            Building building = _service.GetBuildingsForPremise(premise);
            return Ok(building);
        }
    }
```

The routing config is as follows:

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Im getting the error that it can't distinguish between the two methods when I initiate a GET action:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

So my question is Do I need to specify the Route attribute on top of each method and if yes, why? Doesn't the second route (ActionApi) deals with that situation?

Comment: How are you calling the Premises actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I just tested you're code and it works the way it is... maybe just it is unclear.

- /api/Premises/Premise/8 --> will take you to your first action
- /api/Premises/Building/8 --> will take you to your second action
- /api/Premises/8 --> will cause error because the routing will go to  the first rule api/{controller}/{id} with a GET request, then he can't distinguish which of the actions you want because they both match the first route: (api/Premises/{id})

Comment: so I would call them by /api/Premises/GetPremise?id=xxx and /api/Premises/GetBuilding?id=xxx without adding either ActionName or Route?

Comment: without adding Name or Route the call is the same for both:
/api/Premises?id="somestring" or /api/Premises/somestring

the method name is irrelevant...(its not like MVC)

Comment: Okay so what is the difference between the two routes:
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
and
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the RoutePrefix attribute on your controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/premises")]
public class PremisesController : ApiController
```

That combined with the route attribute would mean you shouldn't get multiple actions with the same route